# Handle error in react form having many fields

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
<Form.Input
            label="Name"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChangeName}
            />
<Form.Input
            label="Age"
            type="number"
            value={this.state.age}
            onChange={this.handleChangeAge}
            />
<Form.Input
            label="Gender"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.gender}
            onChange={this.handleChangeGender}
            />
<Button
                className="primaryButton"
                onClick={this.onSave}
            >
            SAVE
            </Button>


handleChangeAge=(e,{value})=>{
   //Set the value to state if it is greater than 1 else show error message.
}


  handleChangeGender=(e,{value})=>{
 //I have some error handling here also
}

onSave=()=>{
//Highlight the fields with errors
}
```

I have a form as shown above.I want to validate each field of the form based on some condition.
How can I handle the error for each field and display it when save is clicked?

Comment: This might help you! https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik

Comment: Is there any other way to do it other than using formik?

Comment: There are many ways. You can also do it manually using plain vanilla js but I would recommend using any mature library to perform validation. @Denis has already suggested Yup.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a proper package to handle this kind of validation for you. If you combine `Formik` with `Yup` you end up with a very consistent form. You can create great validations with `Yup`

Formik: https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik

Yup: https://github.com/jquense/yup

:)

Comment: Is there any other way to do it other than using formik?

Comment: Well, yes. Each time that the text value changes you must validate with your rules and maybe control if this input is wrong with some state as well, like `genderError`, `genderErrorMsg` and etc...Then display it this message below your input, change the input's color based if `genderError` is true and etc...
I think this a lot of work and using Formik and Yup would save you a lot of time and you will end up with a better solution.

Comment: Okay . Thanks a lot :)  Denis Cappelini

Comment: You are welcome :). Could you mark as a good answer, if it helped you? Thanks!

Comment: I have marked it as useful.Since my reputation is not more than 15 it won't be displayed publicly but the votes will be considered.